# How to break table after specific number of rows xsl-fo 1.0?

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have a problem with memory while using apache fop for export tables to pdf.
I want to try solve this problem by breaking my large table after specific number of rows(for example after 10 rows). How can i break table after specific number of rows using xls-fo 1.0?

Comment: Are using XSLT or Java code to generate the XSL-FO that you feed to FOP?

Comment: you want seperate table for each group of 10 rows, or breaking page after 10 rows?

Answer (score 1):

While generating row you can use below condition whilch may help you to generate desire output:

```
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <xsl:for-each select="student">
                                <fo:table-row padding-top="0pt" padding-bottom="0pt">
                                    <xsl:if test="position() mod 10 = 0">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="break-before">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="'page'"/>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>
                                            <fo:inline font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                            </fo:inline>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:block>
                                            <fo:inline font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="class"/>
                                            </fo:inline>
                                        </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </fo:table-body>
```

Comment: it will generate every 10 row group per page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in XSL-FO.  You have to change your Java code to generate a separate `fo:table` for each group of 10 rows.

Comment: Or use xslt to process the xsl fo first but should be easier in java if OP wrote the code